# JQuery - Can't reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have one PHP page with a form, checkboxes and a submit button, and i inserted a if isSet at this button, to run a PHP script that i created when the button is clicked, at this case, my code deletes some values from the checked rows.

The button is working fine, when i click at the button, it changes specific values.

But i have to manually reload the page to see the values definitely eliminated, so i got the idea to auto reload the page when the button is clicked using JQuery, i'm using this simple script:

```
$('.delete').once('click', function(){
     window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

The problem is that when i click at the button, nothing happens, it reloads, but the values that i deleted still there, and i have to reload manually to kick the values that i eliminated.

But when i click at the button again without checking nothing, it reloads, and refresh the page without the values that i deleted.

I have to click two times at the button to kick out the deleted values.

I'm using window load

```
   $(window).load(function(){
```

Here the code from the button:

```
<input style='width: 50px;' class='delete' value='delete'  type='submit' name='del[]' />
```

I dont want to refresh using HTML, i prefere JQuery

I have no idea why i can't refresh the page at the same time when i update my values.

It must be because the PHP runs first...

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Never heard of `.once()`. Is that right? I think you are looking for `.one()`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Most browser cache values, you can "kinda" force a reload, by changing the url.

To do this use something like:

```
var curHref = window.location.href;
window.location.href = curHref + (curHref.indexOf('?')===-1?'?':'&') + new Date().getTime();
```

this will append a timestamp the href and should trigger a complete new load. If you already